# How to automate section headers and code chunks in quarto

Tags: r, automation, r-markdown, quarto

I would like to automate titles and code chunks in quarto. I have a vector
`x<-c("title1","title2", "title3")` and a function `figure(x)`. What I would like to do is use quarto to create a document with the pattern ##title1, code chunk with figure("title1"), ##title 2, etc. without having to actually write out
##`r x[1]`
`{r} figure(x[1])`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps.

Create a quarto file. Give it a name. eg `quarto_example.qmd`

Run the following code

````
f <- function(x, my_file){
  cat("## ", x, "\n```{r}\n",
      "figure(", x, ")\n```\n\n", sep="",
      append = TRUE, file = my_file)
} 
vec <- c("title1", "title2", "title3")
invisible(sapply(vec, f, my_file = "quarto_example.qmd"))
````

---

If the function also changes, you will have to pass it as an argument:

````
f <- function(x, fun, my_file){
  cat("## ", x, "\n```{r}\n",deparse(substitute(fun)),
      "(", x, ")\n```\n\n", sep="",
      append = TRUE, file = my_file)
} 

invisible(sapply(paste0("title", 1:5), f, figure, "quarto_example.qmd"))
````

Note that the code is error-prone. ie running it more times will continuously write the code into the file. There are no checks done to determine as to whether the file already has the code to be written. You could do the check using `grep/grepl` or even manually